# JQuery Datatables column sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, user-interface, datatables

I have a problem with JQuery DataTables (datatables.net) that when I have only 2  (rows) in the table it takes 2 clicks to sort the columns (the first column sorts first click, the others are hit and miss, mostly 2 clicks). 
I tested this thoroughly. I am using JQuery UI Tabs which doesn't affect it. Below is the entire html document.

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/datatables/datatables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#table_id').DataTable({

    });
});
</script>
<body>
<center>
<table id="table_id" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
            <tr>
        <th>icon</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Ilvl</th>
            <th>Req</th>
            <th>Side</th>
            <th>Slot</th>
        <th>Source</td>
        <td>Type</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
        <th>icon</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Ilvl</th>
            <th>Req</th>
            <th>Side</th>
            <th>Slot</th>
        <th>Source</td>
        <td>Type</td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>253</td>
                <td>614</td>
                <td>E2531h</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>12532ett Winters</td>
                <td>435countant</td>
                <td>264Tokyo</td>
                <td>23463</td>
                <td>342011/07/25</td>
                <td>34$170,750</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3241Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>145Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>324San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>


        </tbody>
    </table>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

If you remove one of the  rows then the problem will occur.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: it works fine in the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/2x8L9b73/

Comment: You need to remove the third <tr>. Please reread my first post. It shows the problem in jfiddle as well.

Comment: removed the third tr , still works fine. https://jsfiddle.net/2x8L9b73/1/

Comment: I'm not sure you are understanding the problem. In the link you just sent me, right after it loads, click name. It doesn't sort until you click it a second time. Then click the first link you sent me and do the same. It sorts on first click.

Comment: Sorry now I got the question

Comment: It's working as expected. Since all the fields have a default sort by 'asc'. 'Name ' is already sorted so are the next few fields . But  if you see 'req' the value should change on click only once. Because the fn has to sort the column on 'asc'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the default sort is ascending, it's working like it supposed to. It's obvious that it will take two clicks to sort columns like 'Name', 'Ilvl', 'Side' etc., because they all are sorted by default 'asc', when you have clicked on the 'icon' column.

So when you click on it, there is nothing to change. If you want to change your default sorting order, then you can use the following settings to change the order.

```
 $.fn.dataTable.defaults.column.asSorting = ['desc', 'asc'];
 $.fn.dataTable.defaults.aaSorting = [[0,'desc']];
```

I hope this is clear. But if it's not then you can see the fiddle where i have changed the contents of 'Name' column alone. Compare it with the markup you have then you will understand why it doesn't sort

from

```
 <td>435countant</td>
```

to

```
<td>615</td>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/karthick6891/2x8L9b73/2/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/karthick6891/2x8L9b73/2/ Can you check the 'Name' column in this link

Comment: Compare https://jsfiddle.net/2x8L9b73/1/ && https://jsfiddle.net/karthick6891/2x8L9b73/2/ . See what is the difference. the columns are sorted in ascending order by default, If there is nothing to sort then you have to click twice. So that it can sort the column by 'desc'

Comment: Ohhh ok I see now, man I've been dealing with this since yesterday. Thank You!